# Update RecyclerView From Different Tab In Viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` with 2 tabs. Each tab just holds a `Fragment` with a `RecyclerView`. The `RecyclerView` in the first tab holds a list of all `Articles` while the `RecyclerView` in the second tab only holds the list of user's favorite `Articles`. Each `Article` in the first tab has a button in the `RecyclerView` row that allows the user to favorite it. I want new favorites to be displayed automatically (without forcing the user to manually press the refresh button) when the user navigates to the second tab. How can I go about doing this? Essentially I need to add / remove items from the `RecyclerView` which contains the favorites, but from the first fragment.

**Things I have tried**

- Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in the `onRefresh()` method of the favorites fragment. This works, but the performance hit is big because `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not a cheap operation. I would like to avoid this if possible.
- [Tried following this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), and implemented some interfaces. The problem is, when I try to reference the adapter in my fragment from the containing activity, the adapter is always null. I can post code if needed to show what I was doing if this is supposed to be possible.

Now I am considering using SQLite DB to store changes (favorite removals/additions) in the onClickListeners, and then checking that table in the `onResume()` method and processing the changes individually, one by one with `notifyItemChanged()`

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Where you getting your data from? `SQlite` or `internet` ?

Comment: Both kind of. I store identifiers of the favorites `SQLite`. Then I use an API to pull down the individual favorites from the internet based on the keys stored in `SQLite`

Answer (score 0):

For `SQlite` use `CursorLoader` to load data from `SQlite`. You can register to be notified when a data changed in a table. Then your loader will automatically load data again. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15529866/1292557) answer. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404047/cursorloader-notify-data-change) Thread.

For getting data from internet you can use

1. Communicate with 2 `fragments` via parent `Activity`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626004/1292557) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5195026/1292557) answer. [This](https://www.journaldev.com/14207/android-passing-data-between-fragments) tutorial is good for better understanding.
2. `LocalBroadcastManager` to notify from one fragment to another fragment.